# Finding the solutions to $(z+1)^8-z^8=0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

So dividing the equation by $z^8$ gives $\left(\frac{z+1}{z}\right)^8=1$
Which gives $\left(\frac{z+1}{z}\right)=e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{8}}$ for $k=0,1...7$

$\therefore\left(\frac{z+1}{z}\right)=e^{i0}$,  $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$, $e^{i\frac{2\pi}{4}}$, $e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}}$...$e^{i\frac{7\pi}{4}}$
Then re-arranging for $z$ gives $z=\frac{1}{e^{i0}-1}$, $\frac{1}{e^{i\pi/4}-1}$, $\frac{1}{e^{i2\pi/4}-1}$ ...$\frac{1}{e^{i7\pi/4}-1}$

My question is; Is this the most elegant way(because this way is a bit clunky if I typed out the full working)? And how do I know which solution to eliminate because I have $8$ but the original polynomial is degree $7$?

Comment: Look more closely, $z=1/(e^{i0}-1)$ does not work.

Comment: @dxiv   $z=\infty$ is that solution.

Comment: z = infinity is not a solution. but as you notice, ((z+1)/z) tends towards 1 as |z| tends towards infinity. the other 7 are solutions

Comment: @herbsteinberg The question is tagged `polynomials` and `complex-numbers`, so I don't think the extended complex plane figures in the picture here.

Comment: I'll leave it to Quippy whether he wants ut or not.

Comment: the Mobius transformation $\frac{1}{z-1}$   maps the real line to the real line (real coefficients)  and maps the circle $|z| = 1$  to a straight line, with constant real part. It is the real number $1$  that is sent off to infinity. If we write $z = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta,$  what is the complex number  $\frac{1}{z-1}  \;  ?  \; \; $  Oh, your 8  points on the unit circle are $\pm 1 , \;  \pm i, \;  \pm \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}  \pm \frac{i\sqrt 2}{2} \; \; \; $